# Task running for min. amount of time

Tags: task, delay

I wish to have some static class I can call to do some action1, then wait for a while and then do action2. Simple as that. No cancellation, no tricks though async. Like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DelayedTask.Run2(() => Console.WriteLine("Hey "), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3), () => Console.WriteLine("you!"));

        Console.WriteLine($"Press any key to end program");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

After a while I came up with 4 solutions, like this:

```
public static class DelayedTask
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Run with delay.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="firstAction"></param>
    /// <param name="delay"></param>
    /// <param name="lastAction"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static async Task Run1(
        Action firstAction,
        TimeSpan delay,
        Action lastAction) =>
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            firstAction();
            Thread.Sleep(delay);
        }).ContinueWith(_ => lastAction()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    public static async Task Run2(
        Action firstAction,
        TimeSpan delay,
        Action lastAction) =>
        await Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[] 
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                firstAction();
                Thread.Sleep(delay);
            })
        }, _ => lastAction()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    public static async Task Run3(
        Action firstAction,
        TimeSpan delay,
        Action lastAction) =>
        await Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[]
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                firstAction();
                Thread.Sleep(delay);
            })
        }, _ => lastAction()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    public static async Task Run4(
        Action firstAction,
        TimeSpan delay,
        Action lastAction) =>
        await Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(new[]
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                firstAction();
                Thread.Sleep(delay);
            })
        }, _ => lastAction()).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

After running Run1(...) -> 4 they all did the same and it seems to me that this is really just a solution in 4 falvours. Am I missing something or can I just choose? Key feature: I suppose Sleep is the way to delay it(?) - Task.Delay(...) did not work here. And another thing in Run3+4(...) things work without any t.Start(...); (?). Actually if I say t.Start(...) last step is not executed.

Nb. Assume action1 runs shorter than delay.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `StartNew`, `ContinueWith`, `ContinueWhenAll`, or `ContinueWhenAny`. These are all extremely low-level methods that have [dangerous default behavior](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) and are for advanced use only.

If your methods are synchronous as your method signatures suggest, then something like this would work:

```
public static Task Run(Action firstAction, TimeSpan delay, Action lastAction) =>
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
      firstAction();
      Thread.Sleep(delay);
      lastAction();
    });
```

If you need to support asynchronous methods, you can do this:

```
public static Task Run(Func<Task> firstAction, TimeSpan delay, Func<Task> lastAction) =>
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
      await firstAction();
      await Task.Delay(delay);
      await lastAction();
    });
```

Comment: Thank you - most help full and so is your blog. Though I still dont understand why is is such a big deal to swop sheduler for a continuation? Is is a matter of time/memory use or something? I mean as long as I can manage to keep my task out of reach of any UI-thread it should be ok to use whatever sheduler - or?

Comment: @MichaelPauli: The problem isn't the scheduler; it's the APIs on those types. Some of the overloads take an optional scheduler, and if you don't pass it, then it defaults to the current scheduler. And "current scheduler" doesn't mean what people think it means most of the time. See the linked blog post for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Steven:

```
    public static Task Run5(
        Func<Task> firstAction, 
        TimeSpan delay, 
        Func<Task> lastAction) =>
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await firstAction();
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            await lastAction();
        });
    public static Task Run6(
        Action firstAction,
        TimeSpan delay,
        Action lastAction)
    {
        Func<Task> firstTask = () => { firstAction(); return Task.CompletedTask; };
        Func<Task> lastTask = () => { lastAction(); return Task.CompletedTask; };

        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await firstTask();
            await Task.Delay(delay);
            await lastTask();
        });
    }
```